# Не срабатывает одновременное нажатие клавиш

Tags: javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (e.code == 'KeyW' && e.code == 'KeyQ') {
        console.log('yes')
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придется проверять нажатие нужных клавиш, запоминать при совпадении в массив, а затем проверять нужное количество. Об этом есть на learn.javascript.ru [отследить одновременное нажатие](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/check-sync-keydown)

```js
let keys = [];
let res = document.querySelector('.result');
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.code == 'KeyQ' || event.code == 'KeyZ') {
    keys.push(event.code)
  }
  if (keys.includes('KeyQ') && keys.includes('KeyZ') ) {
    res.innerHTML = 'yes';
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  keys.length = 0;
  res.innerHTML = '';
});
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
```